# NetworkLink kml file works in Google earth but not on Google maps (the browser map is just a bare map without any placemarks)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, kml

I have a very simple NetworkLink kml (below) file that has a href tag to an .aspx file that generates dynamic placemarks (with `<Placemark id="1">`, `<name>`, `<description>`, `<Point>`, `<coordinates>` as tags).  The NetworkLink kml file works in Google earth but not on Google maps (the browser map is just a bare map without any placemarks) and I’m at a loss as to why.

NetworkLink kml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
    <NetworkLink>
        <name>Ticket Map Add-In</name>
        <Link>
            <href>http://66.230.78.217/getKML.aspx</href>
        </Link>
    </NetworkLink>
</kml>
```

.js that actually shows (or should show but doesn’t) the placemarks on the map:

```
    window.onload = function () {
        initialize();
    }
    var map;
    var infowindow;
    var service;
    var request;

    function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var startLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.82177, -72.50722);
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            center: startLatLng,
            zoom: 5
        });
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://66.230.78.217/netLink.kml');
        ctaLayer.setMap(map);
    }
```

Any explanation of a reason why would be greatly appreciated

Link to the page that does not work:
http://66.230.78.217/ResultsGeneral.aspx

****Update****

I'm begining to think that its a problem with the NetworkLink file.  I can't load any file (kml or aspx) using `<NetworkLink><Link><href>`... but I can load the same kml file directly in the javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is because your server is taking too long to create the KML.  You can test this theory by saving a static version of your KML on your server and having the NetworkLink call that instead.

Additionally you should set the MIME type for your KML appropriately, as noted in http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kml_tut.html#kml_server

Comment: Is there any way to customize the time limit (the server is incredibly slow so it is very likely that this is an/the issue).

Comment: Nope; you need to make your server answer faster.  Try adding some caching perhaps -- does it really need to create a unique KML each time?

Comment: I actually don't think that's the issue because the server side part should be fully loaded before any of the client side JavaScript loads and because a static file loaded directly from the javascript loads but the same file using a networklink href tag does not load this same file.

Comment: In that case, to isolate the issue, can you update your codesample above (or provide here) the link to your static file so we can test the NetworkLink with that?  It should work ...  Note you can also just go to http://maps.google.com?q=http://your.kml to test